# Google API php client and service account: date of event missing

Tags: php, google-api

I have some php code like this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'your calendar id';
$optParams = array(
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
  'maxResults' => 100,
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
);

$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

// in order to use it in javascript
echo json_encode($events);
```

$events is the expected array but does not contain the date of each event. i did some testing before i was utilizing a service account and each date was accessible via the property "start" but not in the list that i'm getting now. any ideas as there is no proper documentation on what i'm supposed to get as response? btw. altering share rights of the service account in the calendar settings does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i figured this out. i was confused as the documentation on this is quite confusing at least to me.

$events is indeed the correct list, but the reason it doesn't contain all the properties mentioned in the docs is that some properties have to be retrieved via method invocation. so what we'll need to do is:

```
// start of first event
$startDate = $events[0]->getStart();
```

this is what my entire script looks like now. excuse my php, never used it before

```
<?php

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setAuthConfig('your service account json secret');

    $client->setApplicationName('your application name');
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    // make actual request
    $calendarId = 'your calendar id';
    $optParams = array(
      'timeMin' => date('c'),
      'maxResults' => 100,
      'singleEvents' => TRUE,
      'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    );

    // of type Events.php
    $events = $service->events;

    // list of items of type Event.php
    $eventItems = $events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams)->getItems();

    // compose an result object, we're only interested in summary, location and dateTime atm
    // don't know if this is considered proper php code, works though
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($eventItems); $i++)
    {
        $result[$i]->{summary} = $eventItems[$i]->getSummary();
        $result[$i]->{location} = $eventItems[$i]->getLocation();
        $result[$i]->{startDate} = $eventItems[$i]->getStart()->getDateTime();
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```